# TypeScript overloads: return type conditional on enum parameter

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to specify the return type based on an enum parameter to the function.

This works:

```
GetDoc(dbType: dbTypes.Responses, id: string): Promise<PouchResponse>;
GetDoc(dbType: dbTypes.Questionnaires, id: string): Promise<PouchQuestionnaire>;
GetDoc(dbType: dbTypes, id: string): Promise<PouchQuestionnaire | PouchResponse> {
    if (dbType === dbTypes.Responses)
        return new PouchDB<PouchResponse>("responses").get(id);
    if (dbType === dbTypes.Questionnaires)
        return new PouchDB<PouchQuestionnaire>("questionnaires").get(id);
    throw "Invalid dbType";
}
```

But now I want to move the `new db` into it's own function, so I do this:

```
GetDB(dbType: dbTypes.Responses): PouchDB.Database<PouchResponse>;
GetDB(dbType: dbTypes.Questionnaires): PouchDB.Database<PouchQuestionnaire>;
GetDB(dbType: dbTypes): PouchDB.Database<PouchQuestionnaire | PouchResponse> {
    if (dbType === dbTypes.Responses)
        return new PouchDB<PouchResponse>("responses");
    if (dbType === dbTypes.Questionnaires)
        return new PouchDB<PouchQuestionnaire>("questionnaires");
    throw "Invalid dbType";
}

GetDoc2(dbType: dbTypes.Responses, id: string): Promise<PouchResponse>;
GetDoc2(dbType: dbTypes.Questionnaires, id: string): Promise<PouchQuestionnaire>;
GetDoc2(dbType: dbTypes, id: string): Promise<PouchQuestionnaire | PouchResponse> {
    return this.getDB(dbType).get(id); // <<-- error here: dbTypes is not assignable to dbTypes.Responses
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try `return this.getDB(dbType.Responses).get(id);`

Comment: Presumably you mean `dbTypes.Responses`? Wouldn't that always then return the Responses data? What if I wanted to call it with dbTypes.Questionnaires? The method would ignore the param and just use the fixed enum constant?

Comment: I'm not getting why are you using these two declarations                               GetDB(dbType: dbTypes.Responses): PouchDB.Database<PouchResponse>;
GetDB(dbType: dbTypes.Questionnaires): PouchDB.Database<PouchQuestionnaire>;

Comment: Are you doing something like this? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html

Comment: I have an enum (dbTypes) which I want to pass to a function with a document Id, and have that function return a document from the appropriate Pouch database. If the enum is Questionnaires, then the function should open the "questionnaires" database and return a Questionnaires type. If the enum is a Response, it should open the "responses" database and return a Response type. This means I don't have to write the same function for each class that I want to store in pouch - I just add an enum and the function handles it.